# Tag-flipping, share culture. How to make agents flipp other string values representing culture

Tags: string, binary, netlogo, culture

I'd like to make the agents share their culture with others. They have a string of length 11 representing their culture, made of binary tags (for example, 10100111101). 
So, for sharing their culture with each friend, they select a random tag. If the friend agrees with the agent at that tag position, no change is made; if they disagree, the friend's tag is flipped to agree with the agent's tag (Epstein and Axtell, GAS).

For more detail, the culture setup is as follows:

```
set t-culture-tags n-values 11 [random 2]
```

And later, for subsetting purpose, I filter like this to count the 0s and give them a group:

```
set shared-culture (filter [i -> i = 0] t-culture-tags)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`replace-item`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#replace-item):

```
turtles-own [ t-culture-tags ]

to setup
  clear-all
  create-turtles 10 [ set t-culture-tags n-values 11 [random 2] ]
end

to go
  ask turtles [
    let friend one-of other turtles
    let i random length t-culture-tags
    let my-tag item i t-culture-tags
    let friend-tag [ item i t-culture-tags ] of friend
    if my-tag != friend-tag [
      set t-culture-tags replace-item i t-culture-tags friend-tag
    ]
  ]
end
```

Answer (score 2):

```
turtles-own [ t-culture-tags ]

    to setup
      ca
      reset-ticks
      crt 10 [
        set t-culture-tags n-values 11 [ random 2 ]
        setxy random-xcor random-ycor
        set color sum t-culture-tags + 50
      ]

    end
```

That setup creates 10 turtles with `t-culture-tags` as in your example above. Now, since you say that a change only occurs if the tags differ between the acting turtle and its friend, it's probably simplest to just always spread the culture of the asking turtle (since, in effect, that causes no change to the `t-culture-tags` of the friend).

So, you can pick a random number from 0 to 10 and use that as an index, then have the asking turtle spread its tag at that index position to all of the "friends" you want. In the example below, each tick one random turtles spreads its culture to all other turtles within a radius of 5:

```
to spread-culture

  ask one-of turtles [
    let tag-index random 11
    let my-tag-at-index item tag-index t-culture-tags

    if any? other turtles in-radius 10 [
      ask other turtles in-radius 10 [
        set t-culture-tags replace-item tag-index t-culture-tags my-tag-at-index
        set color sum t-culture-tags + 50
      ]
    ]
  ]
  tick

end
```

If you run that for a while, you will see that all turtles that are within a radius of one-another will eventually have identical t-culture tags, represented in this example by their color.